# Removing Code Linking for Different Targets in XCode - iAds

Tags: iphone, ipad, linker, compiler-errors, iad

I have an app I am working on which has been split into two targets, one for the iPhone and one for the iPad. The iPhone side (w/iAds) runs perfectly, but the iPad target gives me errors. It basically boils down to the iPad target not recognizing the iAd framework.

I've tried weak linking but I still get `iAd/iAd.h: No such file or directory` as an error. Obviously iAds can't be run on the iPad but I at least need my code to compile.

Am I missing some blatantly obvious solution here?

Answer (score 1):

The iAd framework — including the headers — does not exist prior to 4.0.

You could try

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 40000  // 40000 == __IPHONE_4_0
#include <iAd/iAd.h>
#endif
```

to ensure the iAd framework is *not* included when compiling for 3.2 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a better way... you have to setup "weak" not required in the frameworks for targets.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more?